# Storing and updating current minimum in vector through class

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement a data structure which makes getting the minimum element in a vector faster by storing the current minimum. `v` is a vector, defined as a private variable of the `cont` class.

The index of the minimum element in the vector is stored in a private variable of `cont` called `mindex`. `mindex` is initialized to 0 by the default constructor for this class.

I am updating the minimum whenever I insert a new element:

```
void cont<T>::insert(const T & newItem, int index){ 
    v.insert(v.begin() + index, newItem);
    if (newItem < v[mindex]) mindex = index;    
}
```

I am also running `updatemin()`(defined below) whenever the element at `mindex` is popped:

```
T cont<T>::pop_front(){
    T elem = v.front();
    v.erase(v.begin()); 
    if (mindex == 0) updatemin();       
    return elem;
}

T cont<T>::pop_back(){
    T elem = v.back();
    v.pop_back();
    if (mindex == v.size() - 1) updatemin();
    return elem;
}

T cont<T>::remove(int index){
    T elem = v[index];
    v.erase(v.begin() + index);
    if (index == mindex) updatemin();   
    return elem;
}
```

`updatemin()` is defined as follows:

```
void cont<T>::updatemin() {
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) 
        if (v[i] < v[mindex]) mindex = i;
}
```

However, `mindex` does not contain the right values when these functions are executed. Running `updatemin()` before returning `mindex` returns the right value. What could be the problem?

Comment: There is a standard algorithm `std::min_element` to find the min for you.

Comment: But I would like to store the minimum and return it

Comment: Use it in your updatemin function.

Comment: Why do you need the minimum to keep being updated?  Just compute the minimum when you need it.  Unless you can explain, I see no utility in knowing the minimum at all times or keep (in your case erroneously) updating a member variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some issues in keeping track of min. The reason of all of which is that you're not considering that the index of the min actually changes when you insert, delete, etc:

1- In the insert function, you didn't consider that if the new number is inserted at an index before mindex, then mindex should be incremented before comparison:

```
void cont<T>::insert(const T & newItem, int index){ 
    v.insert(v.begin() + index, newItem);
    if (index < mindex) mindex++;
    if (newItem <= v[mindex]) mindex = index;    
}
```

2- pop_front:

```
T cont<T>::pop_front(){
    T elem = v.front();
    v.erase(v.begin()); 
    if (mindex == 0) updatemin();
    else mindex--;       
    return elem;
}
```

3- remove:

```
T cont<T>::remove(int index){
    T elem = v[index];
    v.erase(v.begin() + index);
    if (index == mindex) updatemin();
    else if (index < mindex) mindex--;   
    return elem;
}
```

Best of luck

Comment: in insert, shouldn't the statement be `if (index <= mindex) mindex++`

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::min_element` along with `std::distance` to get the minimum index:

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
void cont<T>::updatemin() 
{
    mindex = std::distance(v.begin(), std::min_element(v.begin(), v.end()));
}
```

Comment: is this faster than `mindex = min_element(v.begin(), v.end()) - v.begin();`

Comment: and I don't think the problem is in the updatemin function, the index is not being stored/updated properly

Comment: Your method of subtraction will not work if you change your container to a `std::list` or `std::deque`.

Comment: In addition, `std::distance` when given random access iterators (vector's iterators are of this type) does a simple subtraction, at least on my version of Visual Studio 2013.  Therefore you are not losing anything by using `std::distance` and instead, gaining the ability to plug in most other sequence containers such as `std::list`, std::deque`, etc.